# How to register service without adding it to Funq container

Tags: servicestack, mef

I want my service to be registered only in custom ioc container. When it is registered in both - Funq and custom - and TryResolve<> of ContainerAdapter fails Funq creates instance of my service with null references without throwing any error.

This is because I am using MEF and dependencies aren't injected using ImportingConstructor, but using private fields.

Answer (score 0):

You can register your dependencies in your Custom IOC but ServiceStack Services are only ever registered in Funq where it's able to assert deterministic behavior.